# How to make set size rows in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzTVf.png)

Hi all, I can't seem to get this working in bootstrap. I've attached an image at the top of this post. I've got two columns, both 6 so they span exactly half the row. However, on the right side I have three rows I'd love to be an equal set size, however I don't know the best way of doing this.

Here's a quick look at what my code looks like (it's just the format I've typed in here)

```
<div class= "row>
  <div class="col-6>
    ~IMAGE~
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      TEXT CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      TEXT CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      TEXT CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's similar to the image I posted at the top, but the rows aren't equal sizes and fluctuate depending on text.
Thanks!

Comment: By equal size rows, do you mean equal height rows?

Comment: Will the rows have any actual content? Couldn't you set the height on them?

Comment: @Sean Yes, equal height

Comment: @j08691 It's dynamic content, so one of the rows often pushes the other rows down, plus aren't actually spaced out correctly, they are all squished at the top of the col

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flex on your right column to evenly space the rows inside.

```css
.col-6 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
    This is where an image will go<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-around">
    <div class="row">
      TEXT CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      TEXT CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      TEXT CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```